# Two Separate CSS Style Background Image Different Colours

Tags: css, html, colors, background

So currently, I have two styles.

```
    .wrapper-style1
{
    background-image:url(../images/river.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    color: #eee;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

    .wrapper-style1 .title
    {
        background-image:url(../images/river.jpg);
        color: #fff;
    }
```

My problem is for some reason the colours don't seem to match within the background.

The wrapper-style1 is fine, but wrapper-style1 .title seems to be darker =S

Any advice?

Site is: www.s1magazine.co.uk

The 'ABOUT S1' background should be same colour as the background below it.

Comment: its becouse the sky is gradient

Answer (score 1):

I made a screenshot and copied the part from about s1 and copied it above the other part. And it is exactly the same image. So you need to adjust the background position

```
 background-position: top center;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Brutus! Works perfectly now =D